# Connect Apple Pencil second generation to Surface Laptop?

Tags: windows, apple-pencil

I was wondering, have anyone thought of connecting apple pencil (1st or 2nd) generation to the surface line in windows 10?

If so, how was it done? any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no official support for connecting the Apple Pencil (1st or 2nd gen) with the Microsoft Surface line.

In addition, there's currently no unofficial projects either.

This means that your only option for connecting the two is to develop your own driver. This will require very significant amounts of skill and knowledge as an engineer. You'll need to reverse engineer the software protocols needed, and you'll most probably need to develop extra hardware in order to make the two compatible.

In short: In practice, this is not possible. It requires so significant investments in time and resources that you could just as well buy a compatible pen or a different tablet.

Comment: @rsc05 Adding to the already well written answer, not even all the iOS devices fully support the Apple Pencil(s) either. Respective models of Apple Pencil are "only" compatible with the iPad Pro models. With other iPads and iPhone, they can be used as dumb stylus. That's also true for Windows Surface devices, Apple Pencils can be used as dumb stylus.

Comment: Apple Pencil 1 can be used with the iPad 6th Generation. I use it all the time.